# Slicer filter with time interval based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

Sample of data:

ID  Date myValue

1   1/09/2019   7

2   1/09/2019   3

3   2/09/2019   2

4   3/09/2019   5

5   4/09/2019   2

I need to create 3 slicers:

-   The first one gives the possibility to choose a specific date ( date picker), I set the date range to Before.

-   The second one gives the possibilty to choose the previous time interval (day, week, month, quarter or year) based and from date that is selected on the first slicer

-   The third one gives the possibilty to choose resolution on the x axis. Example if you chose year as time interval on the second slicer, then you can choose the resolution on x axis from day, week, month or quarter

So far all I could achieve is creating some dynamic measures that change the resolution but no succes with making time intervals.

Has somebody tackle this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

according to what i understand from your text, i suggest you to create a table which includes only dates

```
DATE TABLE=CALENDAR(DATE(2019,11,1),DATE(2023,5,1)) #start date, end date it goes one by one
```

Then make a relation with you Date Column in your Data with DATE TABLE. now you can arrange your slicer however you want

[image]